# Solr-Collection or Core not reloading schema.xml

Tags: solr, reloading

I am using Solar 4.6 and changed something inside `schema.xml`. In order to update `schema.xml` inside my core I used `zkcli`. Which works fine and I am able to see the modified `schema.xml` inside the Solr Admin GUI under `cloud\tree\config\foobar\schema.xml`.

But after calling

- `http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=RELOAD&name=foobar` and
- `http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=RELOAD&name=foobar`,

the old `schema.xml` was still in the core named foobar.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reload your cores after giving it a new schema.

Replace name with core in your query as:

```
/solr/admin/cores?action=RELOAD&**core**=yourcorename
```

For example

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=RELOAD&core=foobar
```

Comment: This is the right answer, another, less technical way is just to simply restart your Tomcat/Jetty server

Answer (score 0):

Your 2nd HTTP request to the Core API is wrong. Change `name` to `core`:

`http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=RELOAD&name=foobar` should be
`http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=RELOAD&core=foobar`.

---

http://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/ref-guide/apache-solr-ref-guide-4.6.pdf (page 277)

## RELOAD

The `RELOAD` action loads a new core from the configuration of an existing, registered Solr core. While the new core is initializing, the existing one
will continue to handle requests. When the new Solr core is ready, it takes over and the old core is unloaded.

This is useful when you've made changes to a Solr core's configuration on disk, such as adding new field definitions. Calling the `RELOAD` action
lets you apply the new configuration without having to restart the Web container. However the Core Container does not persist the SolrCloud
`solr.xml` parameters, such as `solr/@zkHost` and `solr/cores/@hostPort`, which are ignored.

`http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=RELOAD&core=core0`

The `RELOAD` action accepts a single parameter, **core**, which is the name of the core to be reloaded.

---

see also https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/CoreAdmin+API#CoreAdminAPI-RELOAD